# Timer in Global.asax

Tags: .net, global-asax, dispatchertimer

I would like to start a timer when the application is started in IIS.

Do you think that the best place is in Application_Start in Global.asax?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a good place because in that way you can absolutely capture the moment the application pool is started, but this does not mean it has to exist there and not in a Singleton class, for example, which gets initialized from the `Application_Start`.

it really depends on where you will need to use that timer from later on.